# Filter object properties based on array of keywords

Tags: javascript, data-structures, filter

Looking for a way to get only the objects in the 'test' object that contain either one of the 'asSrcElementsTypes' values

What is the best way to map over the array to check if they are any of those values? I keep getting errors with the below code when I try to map the array to see if it matches the key in the test object.

```
var asSrcElementsTypes = ['-input', '-src'];
var test = { "exitUrl":"googl.com", "otherData1":"otherData1" "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input", "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra", "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12", "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input", "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra", "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14", "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10", "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png", "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11", "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"};

const allButMe = data.filter(function(value, key){ if(key.indexOf.indexOf(asSrcElementsTypes.map()) !== -1){return key}});
```

Comment: You only have a single object there, and you have no arrays. What's the desired output?

Comment: *"I keep getting errors "*  ... and what exactly are those errors? The messages and lines they reference are extremely helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something, like that?

```js
const asSrcElementsTypes = ['-input', '-src'],
      test = { "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input", "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra", "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12", "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input", "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra", "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14", "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10", "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png", "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11", "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"},
      
      
      result = Object.fromEntries(
        Object
          .entries(test)
          .filter(([key,value]) => 
            asSrcElementsTypes
              .some(type =>
                key.includes(type)))
      )
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Or, maybe, alternative `.reduce()`-based way:

```js
const asSrcElementsTypes = ['-input', '-src'],
      test = { "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input", "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra", "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12", "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input", "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra", "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14", "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10", "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png", "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11", "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"},
      
      
      result = Object
        .keys(test)
        .reduce((r,key) => (
          asSrcElementsTypes.some(type => 
            key.includes(type)) &&
          (r[key]=test[key]), r), {})
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```