# How do I exclude a list of keys when cloning a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability

I am working on an app with a normalized state in Redux. One of my entities is the 'parent' entity of another, so when I delete that parent entity I want to delete all of the children entities associated with that parent.

For deleting a single entity (1 ID), I have been using this pattern:

```
// ../reducers/entity.js
case DELETE_ENTITY: {
    const entityId = action.payload.entityId;
    const {[entityId]: ignore, ...stateWithoutEntity} = state;
    return stateWithoutEntity;
}
```

For context, the `state` in the above snippet is shaped as such:

```
{
    ID_1: {
        //entity 1 value
    },
    ID_2: {
        //entity 2 value
    },
    // etc...
}
```

Is there a similar patten for deleting a list of multiple entities (n IDs)?

In other words, is there a pattern for cloning a JavaScript object while excluding several keys?

```
// ../reducers/entity.js
case DELETE_PARENT_ENTITY: {
    const parentId = action.payload.parentId;
    const childrenIdsToRemove = action.payload.children;
    // How do I clone the state while excluding each ID in childrenIdsToRemove?
}
```

Comment: Using `Object.entries` / `filter` & `reduce` you can create any filtering logic you want.

Comment: You might want to check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859359/11299053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lots of keys of an object you want to remove, you can use `Object.entries` and then `filter`, and then finally `reduce` to make the final object.

Below is a simple example, that basically remove all keys that start with `entity`.

> Update, Thanks to comments changed to `fromEntries` instead of reduce

```js
const x = {
  'entity1': 1,
  'something': 2,
  'entity2': 3,
  'another': 4
}


const y =
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x)
  .filter(([k]) => !/^entity/.test(k)));
  
console.log(y);
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` is the idiomatic version of that `.reduce`

Comment: @Thankyou  Nice!, updated to use..

Comment: Ended up using this form - thanks Keith!